# Changing values in preprocess view function

Tags: views, theming

I want to preprocess view to alter a field based on another field. I am able to print the value but not change it.

I did this:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_views_view__VIEWNAME(&$vars){

     kpr($vars['view']->result['0']->field_field_name[0]['rendered']['#markup']);
}
```

Which prints the correct value.
But when I try to change/unset the value it does not work. Both of these do not work.

```
 unset($vars['view']->result['0']->field_field_name[0]['rendered']['#markup']);

 $vars['view']->result['0']->field_field_name[0]['rendered']['#markup'] = '';
```

I also tried another way  which prints the value but does not change it:

```
 unset($vars['view']->result['0']->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_name['und'][0]['value']);
```

Note: I am rewriting the results of a field with view UI.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `MYTHEME_preprocess_views_view($vars)` hook is executed at the end of the process to build a view. The purpose of the *views_view.tpl.php* is a general wrapper for all elements of the view. The result of fields have been builded and rendered and they have been stored in the variable `$vars['rows']`.

If you want to change, alter, unset a view, we can do in different phases. Between them, i've chosen the pre-render phase:

```
function HOOK_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if(isset($view->name) && $view->name == 'YOUR_VIEW'){
    // kpr($view);
    foreach($view->result as $r){
      $r->field_field_NAME[0]['rendered']['#markup'] .= '. ADDING TEXT TO CHANGE THE RESULT';  
    }
  }
}
```

These are the stages that are given by Views API (you will find it in the views folder). Maybe one of them is more useful:

```
hook_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {}
```

> Allows altering a view at the very beginning of views processing, before
>     anything is done.

---

```
hook_views_pre_build(&$view)
```

> This hook is called right before the build process, but after displays
>     are attached and the display performs its pre_execute phase.

---

```
hook_views_post_build(&$view) {}
```

> This hook is called right after the build process. The query is now fully
>     built, but it has not yet been run through db_rewrite_sql.

---

```
hook_views_pre_execute(&$view) {}
```

> This hook is called right before the execute process. The query is now fully
>     built, but it has not yet been run through db_rewrite_sql.

---

```
hook_views_post_execute(&$view) {}
```

> This hook is called right after the execute process. The query has
>     been executed, but the pre_render() phase has not yet happened for
>     handlers.

---

```
hook_views_pre_render(&$view) {}
```

> This hook is called right before the render process. The query has been
>     executed, and the pre_render() phase has already happened for handlers, so
>     all data should be available.

---

```
hook_views_post_render(&$view, &$output, &$cache) {}
```

> Post process any rendered data.

Comment: In Drupal 7, what file do you set these hooks? View template or some other file?

Comment: You could set a hook in the template.php file of your custom theme or in your custom module.