# Accessing all VIEW data in a preprocess hook

Tags: views, hooks

I have the following hook method:

```
hook_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$vars)
```

I can obtain the VIEW like so:

```
$view = $vars['view'];
```

When I dump this result I can see a complex structure with all the data I need...the VIEW can be iterated via:

```
foreach ($view->result as $index => $record)
```

Each records data (node details) is navigable via the following path:

```
$record->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_XXX
```

I am uneasy accessing these details with the second property in this chain as usually "underscore" represents private...maybe it is just the OO purist in mean telling me it's bad practice and I am defeating OCP. :)

Ultimately I need the ability to iterate my custom fields and this seems to be the only way I can achieve that -- is there not a API which would encapsulate this access for me?

I assumed the $view object itself would have an API to provide traversing methods or at least result iteration, but it doesn't appear that way.

Comment: Basically I need some confirmation from someone else that this is the "drupal way" and I will move forward :) thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `result` array in the Views object contains the row information so yes, if you need to access the results, this is the way to do it.

For example, including:

```
function YOURMODULE_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {

  $view=$variables['view'];
  drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($view->result, TRUE) . '</pre>');

}
```

and then a quick View that just returns node objects would look like this:

[image]

and a View that returns fields (in this case just titles) would look like this:

[image]

and then when you actually include custom fields, you get that big `_field_data` array, eg:

[image]
[image]

but you should also see it in a more top level area of the results as well:

[image]

Also, a quick look at [views_get_view_result()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7) might shed some more "this is how we do it" confirmation/information on Views results.  Also [What is the hook to preprocess a view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60271/what-is-the-hook-to-preprocess-a-view) and [Changing values in preprocess view function](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78634/changing-values-in-preprocess-view-function) talk about other options available to you in the Views API.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed reply...much appreciated :)

In the template views-view-fields.tpl.php there is a variable $fields['field_content']->content -- I assume this is constructed in the default preprocessor -- anyway I was expecting something similar in that big array instead of having to traverse the rather large VIEWS array

Comment: You are talking about the rendered output of the field(s) and yes, that is constructed in a different stage of the View.  If you could detail what you are trying to accomplish more precisely, some more detail to the answer can be provided for sure.

Comment: I added another custom field called "align" and it's showing up under "_field_data" but not as a "field_field_align" property??? Any ideas?

Comment: what kind of field is it and what is it showing up as?

Comment: I think I figured out why...align is not included in the VIEW query output :) so unless I do that I have to navigate the _field_data property

Comment: Well, sure, for it to be there, it has to be included in the Fields included in the View :)

Comment: I get that now...but it seemed odd to me that it was available in the _field_data property and not as a outer most property field_field_x...in any case I can access all data through _field_data as long as that property doesn't change with a VIEWS update in the future I should be good :) thx for all the help :) much appreciated

Comment: just make sure you use the appropriate hook.  the preprocess one is really used to add variables to the templates, not to modify the $view object.  so look at https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_hooks/7 for a list of them all.  cheers!